# How to use an enemy as a meatbag?

Tags: xbox-360, assassins-creed-3

I've tried everything (I think) and searched and searched, but I can't seem to figure out how to hold an enemy as meatbag when the red coats (or other enemies) start firing at me.

The simple on screen tutorial-text asked me to hold `A` in the beginning (I think) - this came up only for a few seconds and I was distracted at that time, I barley started to read the line when it disappeared and I didn't think much of it.. though, it's coming back to haunt me now.

I'm in the middle of a combat, making short work of my enemies - until a bunch of them decide to shoot me from afar. I've tried tapping `A`, pressing and holding it, double tapping it, pressing it with other buttons etc.. but I just stand there and get hit by the bullets. The only way to escape once I get hit is by running away.. Sometimes I hide behind  people or trees but most times that doesn't work.

So - How do I meatbag my enemies please?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The only way I've noticed it works for me is when I have a enemy that you can usually counter with `B`, and then hit `X` to do an assassination kill.

When the other guards are about to fire, and you are near one of the easy guards that I described above, look at the HUD on the bottom right, at certain times you will see the `A` button show different text for you to grab someone for a shield.

Comment: Oh, so it only works with the lowest ranking enemies?!.. Thank you!

Comment: It might work on the mid to high ranking enemies as well, however I've only had success with the low ones. Also, you should get the hang of it after 4 - 5 times, and then you won't have to look at the HUD when you need to take cover. :)

Comment: The enemy you attempt to use as a meat bag must be low enough range where they won't attempt to counter you.  if you are near such an enemy, all you have to do is press `A` while guards with guns are starting to fire ( yellow warning ).  You can also press `Y` if they are very close to prevent them from shooting you ( single guard ).

Comment: The different text, and the in-game term that is displayed, is "Human Shield".

Comment: Hi, I went back and tried for a bit.. Once I got the hang of it, it was surprisingly easy! thanks so much for your help, it was driving me nuts! Also, I can confirm that you can use not only the enemies with muskets as meatbags, but also those brutes with beards and skirts with huge axe, and the tall hair-hat guys with guns who heads the group (the one who you can't kill with `B` and `X`) and also captains. I wish there was a wiki page describing different enemy types somewhere!

Answer (score 0):

What I have noticed, release the Right Trigger. This keeps you from jumping to the side. So when you see them aiming, simply release the trigger and tap A when near an enemy. I hope this answers your question.

Answer (score -1):

You can press <kbd>a</kbd> when they shoot you, but a foe should be near by you to use him as a human shield.